# Map array into array of tuples of previous, current, and next values

Tags: f#

What is the best way to map the following:

```
[|"A"; "B"; "C"; "D"|]
```

to

```
[|("","A","B"); ("A","B","C"); ("B","C","D"); ("C","D","")|]
```

?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17247164/974789), except you don't need to replicate the values; `yield ""` will do the job.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd prefer approach based on idiomatic combinators: attach an empty string to both ends of array, use [`Seq.windowed 3`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340420.aspx) to produce sequence of sliding arrays of three items, and finally map each sequence element into tuple and convert sequence back to array:

```
let conv source =
    Array.concat [[|String.Empty|]; source; [|String.Empty|]] |> Seq.windowed 3
    |> Seq.map (fun x -> x.[0],x.[1],x.[2]) |> Seq.toArray
```

Testing `conv [|"A";"B";"C";"D"|]` under FSI yields:

```
val it : (string * string * string) [] =
  [|("", "A", "B"); ("A", "B", "C"); ("B", "C", "D"); ("C", "D", "")|]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
let neighbors (xs: _ []) =
  let get i = if i>=0 && i<xs.Length then xs.[i] else ""
  Array.mapi (fun i x -> get(i-1), x, get(i+1)) xs
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the first time I've looked at f# so pardon my attempt if it isn't correct.  I also don't have f# so I can't test this.  But based on [Array.map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353512.aspx)...

```
let data = [|"A"; "B"; "C"; "D"|]
let convert = data |> Array.map (fun x -> (char(int x - 1), x, char(int x + 1)))
printfn "Converting to tupels by using map = %A" convert
```

Hopefully it will point you in the right direction.

Comment: That choice of elements was maybe poor on my part. They won't necessarily be alphabetically consecutive. For example, I might need [|L; F; T|] -> [|( , L, F); (L, F, T); (F, T, )|]